# got at <unknown> <0xffffffff> stacktrace error (see code below)

Tags: xamarin.ios

```
if (this.PendingLocalUARTCreditsCount != 0) return;

this.PendingLocalUARTCreditsCount = this.MaxLocalUARTCreditsCount - this.LocalUARTCreditsCount;
IntPtr value = (IntPtr)(this.PendingLocalUARTCreditsCount);
NSData valueData = NSData.FromBytes(value, 1);
this.CbPeripheral.WriteValue(valueData, this.UartRxCreditsCharacteristic, CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithoutResponse);
```

Got stacktrace error with `NSData valueData = NSData.FromBytes(value, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Native Crash Reporting

=================================================================

Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries  used by your application.

=================================================================

Comment: It seems that you have solved your issue now, please remember to mark your reply as answer, it may be helpful to other community members, thanks.

Comment: Debug output shows Basic fault address reporting. This is because of the pointer (IntPtr) accessing the wrong address probably so when I deference the data in the NSData line of code it crashes. Anybody out there got any clues? Nick.

Comment: I got SIGSEGV error not SIGABRT. I can discover connect and disconnect but not set rx credits on the peripheral because suspect pointer is pointing to wrong address. Don't think I need permissions. Regards nick

Comment: @NickHunterBlair Okey , have a look at this :https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/2920

Comment: Hi junior, app doesn't actually crash it just get stuck with the SIGSEGV error when it actions the line I previously mentioned.

Comment: @NickHunterBlair That's strange . I have checked code `NSData.FromBytes` , it also occurs the error . However , I trid a workaround to avoid using `NSData.FromBytes`. You can have a try with `NSData.FromArray` . I also will udpate answer .

Comment: That's fantastic Junior. Thanks so much for your help. Doesn't show error now. Best regards nick

Comment: @NickHunterBlair Glad to hear that ! Remember to mark it when you have time ,then other people will also see the solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't solved it though in any way. I am developing in C# for an ipad app project using vs 2019 and a, Mac
Nick

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO ! You'd better update content all in question , then other people will know problem more clearly .

Although not knowing why `NSData.FromBytes` occurs error , however there is a workaround for you to check . Using `NSData.FromArray`to transfer `int` to `NSData` .

```
int valueInt = 1234567890;
Byte[] byteData = new Byte[1];
byteData[0] = (Byte)((valueInt & 0xFF));

Console.WriteLine("-----NSData-------" + NSData.FromArray(byteData));
```

Then output is :

```
-----NSData-------{length = 1, bytes = 0xd2}
```

Therefore , shared code can be modified as follow :

```
...
Byte[] byteData = new Byte[1];
byteData[0] = (Byte)((this.PendingLocalUARTCreditsCount & 0xFF));
NSData valueData = NSData.FromArray(byteData);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I got SIGSEGV error not SIGABRT. I can discover connect and disconnect but not set rx credits on the peripheral (using Telit 4.0 Bluetooth low, energy module) and am trying to get communication to work so don't think have to set Bluetooth permissions The problem I think is the pointer (Intpr) pointing to the wrong address as app crashes, when it deferences the data. 
Thanks for the input though. 
Regards nick